# Trouble accessing cell values in ranges (LookupSum function)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble with accessing values of cells in ranges.

The overall challenge is quite complex, but I seem to be falling at an early hurdle, so appreciate thoughts.

```
Function LookupSum(criteriaRng As Range, criteriaHeadRng As Range, lookupColumn As String, DataTable As Range, Optional OffsetRow As Integer) As Integer
'Looks up multiple row values in a lookup column and returns the sum
'criteriaRng and criteriaHeadRng are equally sized horizontal one row high ranges
'Our data table has the criteria down the left column and the lookup header along the top row
'The aim is to sum the values in the correct column where the leftmost row value meets the multiple criteria. There may be multiple criteria entries in the table. Offset can be used to pick the first, second third row consistently. The data table is sorted on the criteria.

'Declarations
Dim criteria() As String, DataColumn As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim FirstColumn As Range, TopRow As Range

'Initialise
LookupSum = 0 'default return
ReDim criteria(20) 'more than enough for this purpose

    
'First get the list of relevant criteria into the criteria() array
i = 0 'set our counters
j = 0
For i = 1 To criteriaRng.Cells.Count
    If criteriaRng(1, i).Value > 0 Then
        criteria(j) = criteriaHeadRng(1, i).Value2
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next
```

Point at which it fails to read anything into criteria(), falling out of the loop with nothing written into criteria(). No error, just showing the cell.value as empty when it isn't (I've checked the address).

If it's a simple mistake you can stop reading here and provide an answer!

Rest of the code for completeness (I haven't tidied this as I want to get the above working)

```
ReDim Preserve criteria(i) 'trim the array back to the useful data only

'Set up lookup columns in the data table - first row and first column
Set FirstColumn = Range("'" & DataTable.Worksheet.Name & "'!" & DataTable(1, 1).Address & ":" & DataTable(DataTable.Rows.Count, 1).Address)
Set TopRow = Range("'" & DataTable.Worksheet.Name & "'!" & DataTable(1, 1).Address & ":" & DataTable(1, DataTable.Columns.Count).Address)

'Find the column required in the data table. This gives us the column count
For Each d In TopRow.Cells
    DataColumn = DataColumn + 1 'loop through and increment the counter
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError(d.Value2) Then If d.Value = lookupColumn Then Exit For 'exit when found. *Need to treat NA() as 0.*
Next d

'Now loop through the data table and retrieve the values to sum based on the required column and the criteria matching in the leftmost column.
l = 0
For k = 1 To i
    For Each e In FirstColumn.Cells
        l = l + 1
        dumb = e.Address
        If criteria(k) = e.Value2 Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError(DataTable(l + OffsetRow, DateColumn).Value2) Then
             LookupSum = LookupSum + DataTable(l + OffsetRow, DateColumn).Value2
            End if
            Exit For
        End If
    Next e
Next k
end function
```

And a screenshot of the challange; aim is to populate the highlighted area:
[image: Screenshot of problem]

Many thanks

Comment: I might be missing something but a simple sumifs function should be able to accomplish this. If you're on an older version of excel then use sumproduct.

Comment: Thanks @DaveMac. The data set I'm using is significantly larger than the above example and SumIF doesn't take nested IF statements to test whether a condition needs to be applied in that instance. I could manually set up using this with a different formula for each country, but that wouldn't be as elegant. There's also the vexing question of why an apparently valid range is returning nothing when queried...

Comment: As suggested, try `SUMIFS`  It takes multiple criteria. Should be quicker than a macro.

Comment: A few questions: what "cell.value" are you referring to? Does criteriaHeadRng contain any values, and does it have the Row count = 1? Why is LookupSum always returning 0 (initialized to 0 and not updated; where do you sum it up)? How do you call LookupSum? A suggestion: replace `Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA()` with `IsNumeric()`. A note: If criteriaRng(1, i).Value = "ABC" then `criteriaRng(1, i).Value > 0` will return True

Comment: Hi @paul, it's the criteriaHeadRng(1, i).Value2 in line 21. criteriaHeadRng would be the {wine, cheese, beer, furniture} array in the screenshot, it's only one row to simplify things. criteriaRng will just contain 0 for false and 1 for true. I've clarified where LookupSum is counted - the return was hidden by an error check. These do need to check for errors as the data table uses errors to avoid populating other graphs. Excel is behaving weirdly. Sometimes criteriaHeadRng(1, i).Value2 gives a value, other times null - same code and input ... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code seems to do the trick. Looks like I was getting i and j mixed up in the criteria array. The `j = j + 1` statement was then adding an extra blank field into the criteria which was throwing the results. I've countered this by looping through to `j-1` in the section to retrieve the indexed values.

Major advantage of this VBA method over SUMIFS is that the formulae are repeatable which was the main objective. The formulae in each cell are much shorter.
Disadvantage of course is that Excel's built in functions are well tested and there may still be errors in this code for various untested boundary conditions or inputs.

Final point to note is that I'm still no nearer figuring out the original question of why `criteriaHeadRng(1, i).Value` didn't work in the original code. It seemed to mysteriously start working as I was making these changes...

```
Function LookupSum(criteriaRng As Range, criteriaHeadRng As Range, lookupColumn As String, DataTable As Range, Optional OffsetRow As Integer)
    'Looks up multiple row values in a lookup column and returns the sum
    'criteriaRng and criteriaHeadRng are equally sized horizontal one row high ranges
    'Our data table has the criteria down the left column and the lookup header along the top row
    'The aim is to sum the values in the correct column where the leftmost row value meets the multiple criteria.

    'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler 'DEBUG code to catch errors

    'Declarations
    Dim criteria() As String, DataColumn As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, l As Integer
    Dim FirstColumn As Range, TopRow As Range, d As Range

    'Initialise
    'LookupSum = 0 'default return
    ReDim Preserve criteria(20) 'more than enough for this purpose

    'First get the list of relevant criteria into the criteria() array
    i = 0 'set our counters
    j = 0
    For i = 1 To criteriaRng.Cells.Count
        If criteriaRng(1, i).Value > 0 Then
            criteria(j) = criteriaHeadRng(1, i).Value
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next

    ReDim Preserve criteria(j) 'trim the array back to the useful data only

    'Set up lookup columns in the data table - first row and first column
    Set FirstColumn = Range("'" & DataTable.Worksheet.Name & "'!" & DataTable(1, 1).Address & ":" & DataTable(DataTable.Rows.Count, 1).Address)
    Set TopRow = Range("'" & DataTable.Worksheet.Name & "'!" & DataTable(1, 1).Address & ":" & DataTable(1, DataTable.Columns.Count).Address)

    'Find the column required in the data table
    For Each d In TopRow.Cells
        dumb = d.Address
        DataColumn = DataColumn + 1 'loop through and increment the counter
        If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError(d.Value2) Then If d.Text = lookupColumn Then Exit For 'exit when found
    Next d

    'Now loop through the data table and retrieve the indexed values
    For k = 0 To j - 1
        l = 0
        For Each e In FirstColumn.Cells
            l = l + 1
            dumb = e.Address
            If criteria(k) = e.Value2 Then
                If Not IsError(DataTable(l + OffsetRow, DataColumn).Value2) Then LookupSum = LookupSum + DataTable(l + OffsetRow, DataColumn).Value2
                Exit For
            End If
        Next e
    Next k

Exit Function
ErrorHandler: 'Debug code - comment/uncomment first line of function
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Source & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    Stop
    Resume
End Function
```

Thanks to all for your comments.